# How to use var/variance function in armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

How should I be using the var() function in armadillo ?

I have a matrix in which rows are variables/features and columns observations/instances.

I which to get the variance of each row so I can determine variables/features with the greatest variance.

Currently I am calling:

```
auto variances = arma::var(data, 0, 1);
```

Where `data` is my matrix.

As far as I can tell at the moment I am getting a matrix ? And the documentation suggests this is correct. I was expecting to get back a single vector with variance scores for each of my matrix rows.

I can loop through my rows and get the variance for each row individually like so:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < data.n_rows; ++i)
    auto rowVariance = arma::var(dataSet.data.row(i));
```

But I would prefer not to do this.

I would like to get back a single vector containing variance values for each row in my matrix and then use arma::sort_index() on this vector to get a sorted set of indices corresponding to the sorted variances.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just write `arma::vec variances = arma::var(data, 0, 1);`. The authors do not recommend to use `auto` since armadillo is a highly templatized class.

Comment: Anyway, you still can declare `mat variances = var(data, 0, 1);` and use `uvec indices = sort_index(variances);`. In this case, `variances` will be a `1xN` matrix, and `indices` will always be a column-vector.

Comment: Hey @vagoberto, Thanks a lot. Turns out the error was because I was using arma::var variances = arma::var(data, 0, 1) and should have been using arma::Col<T> variances = arma::var(data, 0 , 1) due to my data matrix being of type Mat<T> as I'm allowing both float and double point precision only. Thanks for the info. Helped me solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the error was because I was using `arma::var variances = arma::var(data, 0, 1)` and should have been using `arma::Col<T> variances = arma::var(data, 0, 1)`due to my data matrix being of type `arma::Mat<T>` as I'm allowing both float and double point precision only.

The comment above from vagoberto set me on the right track.